# How is it possible to run Ordered test in VS 2015 from bin\debug directory?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, deployment, mstest

I have an ordered mstest (.orderedtest) and every time I try to run it mstest executes it not from output directory (bin\debug) but from TestResults...\out directory. This is the real problem because tests use some files from solution directory and I don`t want to copy them every time before test run. Thanks in advance.

P.s.1 Any test outside of ordered test runs fine

P.s.2 `<DeploymentEnabled>False</DeploymentEnabled>` didn`t help

Comment: After some investigations I`ve found more elegant solution. Don`t know wht <DeploymentEnabled>False</DeploymentEnabled> was not working but .testsettings file works fine. Just do next:
1. Make sure that your project is Unit test project or any equal to it 
2. Right-click Solution in solution explore -> add new item -> test settings -> test settings
3. Open Test settings file
4. Open Deployment tab
5. Uncheck "Enable deployment" checkbox
6. Save changes
7. Specify to use test settings file during the run. (e.g. /testsettings:Local.Testsettings for cmd) works fine for VS 2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can priorities test methods like below.

This test case will execute first

```
[TestMethod]
[Priority(1)]
public void TestMethod1()
{

}
```

This test case will going to execute just after TestMethod1

```
[TestMethod]
[Priority(2)]
public void TestMethod2()
{

}
```

If you will not provide test case priorities then it will going to execute after all priorities test case execution just like below TestMethod3 example.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod3()
{

}
```

Same i am doing in Windows Store (metro/WinRT) apps.